# Not able to send message using SimpMessagingTemplate

Tags: java, spring, stomp

I am trying to send message programmatically to all clients when new client is connected using stomp with spring. But the response on each client I am getting is `undefined`.
I have written code below code for same,

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


@MessageMapping("/connected")
@SendTo("/testApp/chatSystem")
public Chat connectNewUser(ChatMessage message) throws Exception {
    this.userName = message.getMessage();

    String updateForClients = "manual message";
    this.template.convertAndSend("/testApp/chatSystem", updateForClients);

    return new Chat("**User "+message.getMessage()+" connected**");
 }
```

I am  confused why it not sending message correctly.

Below is sample responce on web page,

```
**User user1 connected**

undefined
```

Comment: Find out where that `undefined` is coming from. It looks like a javascript error.

Comment: sorry @Bart, but I am not getting you..

Comment: Just saying that `undefined` is a common value in javascript. Find out why it shows this value. Open up your browser's developer tools and see what the server is sending to the client and why it might end up `undefined`.

Comment: yes @Bart, I checked for the same. Its showing the correct message in browsers developer tool, on console. But on UI its showing "undefined"